# How to create a File (ContentVersion) via Java-based Salesforce Functions using a byte array?

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, salesforce-functions

I have a byte array in Java-based Salesforce Function that needs to end up as a .tiff image in Salesforce as a ContentVersion record (Lightning File tied to a specified parent id).

Here is what I have so far:

```
UnitOfWorkBuilder unitOfWork = context.getOrg().get().getDataApi().newUnitOfWorkBuilder();

String title = "test.tiff";
String parentId = "a0hf000000EQ8eEAAT";
byte[] byteArrayThatIsSupposedToBeBlob = img.frontImageViewData.image; //THIS CONTAINS .TIFF IMAGE AS A BYTE ARRAY

Record checkImage = context.getOrg().get().getDataApi()
                    .newRecordBuilder("ContentVersion")
                    .withField("Title", title)
                    .withField("ContentLocation", "S")
                    .withField("PathOnClient", title)
                    .withField("VersionData", byteArrayThatIsSupposedToBeBlob.toString()) <-- HOW DO I FIX THIS?
                    .withField("FirstPublishLocationId", parentId)
                    .build();

String checkImageReferenceId = unitOfWork.registerCreate(checkImage);

Map<ReferenceId, RecordModificationResult> result = context.getOrg().get().getDataApi().commitUnitOfWork(unitOfWork.build());
```

Notice that I am passing `byteArrayThatIsSupposedToBeBlob.toString()` to `registerCreate` because it doesn't look like the `withField` accepts a byte array directly. When I did `.withField("VersionData", byteArrayThatIsSupposedToBeBlob)` I got:

> The method withField(String, String) in the type RecordBuilder is not
> applicable for the arguments (String, byte[])

This doesn't seem to be creating the content version record at all. Oddly, there is no exception thrown either. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked when I fed a Base64 encoded string to VersionData like so:

```
import java.util.Base64;
.
.
.
byte[] bytes = img.frontImageViewData.image;
.
.
.
.withField("VersionData", Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes))
```